# Change the default currency in crm.lead model (odoo 12)

Tags: python, odoo-12

In the Module: CRM > MyPipeline ,
I want to Change the default currency of the 
'Expected revenue' by the possibility to choose from the activated currencies 
field in res.company model (Currency)

So , I changed the currency field , but does not work

```
class crm_currency(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    planned_revenue = fields.Monetary('Expected Revenue', currency_field='currency_id', track_visibility='always')
```

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `currency_field` option of the `planned_revenue` field in the kanban view.

```
<record id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.lead.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_subtitle')]/t/field[@name='planned_revenue']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="options">{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Make sure that `currency_id` field is not empty or you will get a `TypeError`

```
TypeError: columnState.data[0].data[currencyField] is undefined
```